# Robolectric: findViewById returns null

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

I'm trying to do a very simple test with Robolectric, I want to test if a view exists. which is very similar to the examples in Robolectric's website,
but `findViewById` keeps returning null.

what can be the problem ?

this is the activity:

```
public class SignInActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    }
}
```

this is the test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SignInActivityTests {

    private SignInActivity mActivity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mActivity = new SignInActivity();
        mActivity.onCreate(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldHaveTheCorrectLogo() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(mActivity.findViewById(R.id.signInLogo));
    }
}
```

the layout XML file contains an `ImageView` with the correct id and resource,
running the activity in the emulator works just fine.

Comment: How about if you try ``mActivity.findViewById`` within ``setUp`` method similarly as Robolectric site example does?

Comment: I tried it and its the same.. I don't understand why this isn't working, its very frustrating.

Comment: I have the same issue, somehow id of view in hierarchy is different than id of R class. I reported the bug here: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/6338

Answer (score -1):

I Found the problem, for some reason the new activity wizard created the XML with an android1 tag and not android. probably not what Robolectric is looking for

Comment: Can you please explain with an example what you mean by android1 tag? What did you have and what did you change it to to make it work. A diff would be perfect. Thanks.